# ubuntu 18.04 docker container

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu-18.04

i'm runnung docker on windows 10 desktop. i like to run ubuntu 18.04 docker container. i have pulled ubuntu and ran following docker command
    Docker up -d ubuntu
i'm not seeing image running when i check

```
docker ps
```

instead i see image stopped when i check

```
docker ps -a
```

why it is like this.? like other images i should see ubuntu running when i check

```
docker ps
```

just like wordpress or mysql images.

also i like to mount volume to ubuntu container by using -v tag. let me know if following command is correct or not

```
docker up -d --name ubuntu -p 80:80 -p 22:22 -v /ubuntu:/home ubuntu
```

Comment: Try to get the error message with docker logs command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: "Run Ubuntu in a container" isn't especially meaningful on its own.  You generally package _a single server process_ in a Docker image.  I tend to recommend [this official Docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) as a good starting point.